# Android stop keyboard from pushing views off screen

Tags: android

Hi i have a EditText and a Button that i want to be position and the bottom of the screen and an scrollView with an imageView at the top

When the keyboard pops up it covers up the EditText i currently have this set in my manfiest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

if i use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

my editText and Button move with the keyboard and are positioned at the top of the keyboard which is what i want. But the ScrollView gets pushed up off the screen.

is there a way so that the just the Edittext and button move with the keyboard?

heres my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/levelView" 


     >

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/106"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </ScrollView>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Get help"
            android:background="@color/green_pressed"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:hint="Answer"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"

             >


        </EditText>




</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my activity i have

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        sv.setEnabled(false);
```